# conversion of array of decimal string to biginteger

Tags: java

How can I convert array of string containing decimal numbers to big integer?

eg:

```
String s={"1","2","30","1234567846678943"};
```

My current code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
String s[]= new String[n];

for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
 s[i] = in.next();
}

BigInteger[] b = new BigInteger[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  b[i] = new BigInteger(String s(i));
}
```

Comment: You don't really need to populate an array of `Strings` and convert it later to an array of `BigInteger`. You can do it with just one for loop. `BigInteger[] b = new BigInteger[n]; for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
 b[i] = new BigInteger(in.next());
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
b[i] = new BigInteger(String s(i));
```

should be:

```
b[i] = new BigInteger(s[i]);
```

In other words: you got half of your syntax correct; but then seem to forget how to read an already defined array slot:

- you use [index] square brackets ( "( )" are only used for method invocations)
- No need to specify that "String" type within that expression

Answer (score 0):

Just use `new BigInteger(s[i]);` instead of `new BigInteger(String s(i));`

FYI, you don't really have to use a separate String array to store initial values. You can directly store them in `BigInteger` array. Somewhat like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();

BigInteger[] b = new BigInteger[n];

for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
    b[i] = new BigInteger(in.next());
}
```